# Replacing parts of a matrix

Tags: matrix, scoping

I'm a beginner to Mathematica and to writing scripts in general. I'm currently trying to write a code that will take any element in a matrix higher than a certain threshold value n and set it equal to the average of its four neighbors (i.e. for the (i,j)th element it would use (i-1,j), (i+1,j), (i,j-1), and (i,j+1)), and then print the new matrix.

The goal is to get rid of exceptionally high values--one problem I am foreseeing is two adjacent elements both being greater than n. The other is that whatever I'm doing now isn't working.

Here's the basic idea I'm working with right now:

```
Cooldown[list_, n_] := 
  Module[{d1 = Dimensions[list][[1]], d2 = Dimensions[list][[2]], i, 
    j, temp = {}},

       For[i = 1, i <= d1, i++,
         For[j = 1, j <= d2, j++,

     If[list[[i, j]] >= n, 
      ReplacePart[
       list, {i, 
         j} -> (Plus[list[[i - 1, j]], list[[i + 1, j]], 
           list[[i, j - 1]], list[[i, j + 1]]]/4)]];
     Print[list];
     Return[list];
     ]]];
```

Answer (score 8):

I think you will find what you are looking for with `MedianFilter`

```
mat = RandomReal[{0,1},{50,50}];
Animate[MatrixPlot[MedianFilter[mat,x]],{x,1,5,1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The built-in functions may not always do exactly what you wish. You can make your own filter reasonably straightforwardly. For example, here is a definition that takes a threshold and changes the value to equal the mean in the region whenever the pixel is above that threshold.

```
filt[x_] := Module[{}, meanX = Mean[Flatten[x]];
   center = Floor[Sqrt[Length[Flatten[x]]]/2];
   thisPix = x[[center, center]];
   If[thisPix > thresh, meanX, thisPix]];
```

This can be applied to a matrix fairly straightforwardly and the output visualized (showing here the matrix and the filtered matrix)

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 10}];
img = Image[data];
thresh = 0.8;
GraphicsRow[{img, ImageFilter[filt, img, 1]}, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use image-procession restoration with [`Inpaint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Inpaint.html). Some data with spikes:

```
n = 100;
A = GaussianFilter[#, 3 {3, 1}] &@RandomReal[1, {n, n}] + 
   RandomChoice[{100, 1} -> {0, 0.3}, {n, n}];

ArrayPlot[A, PixelConstrained -> 2, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

After reconstruction:

```
filter[A_, thr_] := ImageData@Inpaint[Image@A, Image@UnitStep[A - thr]];

ArrayPlot[filter[A, 0.7], PixelConstrained -> 2, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A function using `` Developer`PartitionMap `` and `ListConvolve` to replace any element  greater than or equal to a given threshold with the average of its four neighbors:

```
ClearAll[filterF1];
filterF1 = Function[{mat, threshold},
   Block[{xx, func, cm = {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}/4,
    rF = # /. {a_ + b_. xx :> (a/(1 - b))} &},
    func = If[#[[2, 2]] < threshold, #[[2, 2]], rF[ListConvolve[cm, #][[1, 1]]]] &;
    Developer`PartitionMap[func, mat, {3, 3}, 1, 2, xx]]];
```

Example:

```
mm = RandomInteger[9, {4, 6}];
Row[MatrixForm /@ {mm, filterF1[mm, 6]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Another function using `ArrayPad`, `UnitStep` and `ListConvolve`:

```
ClearAll[filterF2];
filterF2 = Function[{mat, threshold}, 
    Block[{xx, m2 = ArrayPad[mat, 1, xx], us = UnitStep[mat - threshold],
     cm = {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}/4, rF = # /. {a_ + b_. xx :> (a/(1 - b))} &},
    mat (1 - us) + Map[rF, us ListConvolve[cm, m2], -1]]];


filterF1[mm, 6] == filterF2[mm, 6]
(* True *)
```

**Notes:** (1) You may wish to add a condition that `threshold` is between the minimum and maximum values in the input matrix. (2) After a single application of `filterF1` you may still have elements in the output matrix that exceed `threshold`. You need to apply the function several times using `Nest` or `FixedPoint` to replace all elements at or above the threshold with the mean of four neighbors. For example:

```
mm = RandomInteger[9, {20, 20}];

Row[MatrixPlot[#, ColorRules -> {_?(# >= 6 &) -> Black},
    ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", ImageSize -> 300] & /@
  {mm, filterF1[mm, 6], Nest[filterF1[#, 6] &, mm, 4]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]